# Integral of absolute value function $f(s,t)=a(2a-1)|t-s|$ over $R^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Hi I'm looking for some help with the function 
$$f(s,t)=a(2a-1)|t-s|^{2a-2}.$$
In particular I'm trying to calculate the integral
$$\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}f(s,t)dsdt=a(2a-1)\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}|t-s|^{2a-2}dsdt.$$

> As Eric Wofsey pointed out this indefinite integral is always
>   infinite, unless a(2a−1)=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This integral is always infinite (unless $a(2a-1)=0$).  Indeed, let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the region where $|t-s|\geq 1$ and let $B\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be the region where $|t-s|<1$.  Note that $A$ and $B$ both have infinite area.  If $2a-2\geq 0$, then the integrand $|t-s|^{2a-2}$ is always at least $1$ on $A$, and so the integral is infinite on $A$.  If $2a-2<0$, then $|t-s|^{2a-2}$ is always at least $1$ on $B$, and again the integral is infinite.